# How to adjust the image brightness in the edge browser

Tags: javascript, microsoft-edge

I have an application and use the following code to adjust the image brightness, it works in Chrome, FireFox and the Chromium based version of Edge, however, it does NOT work in the EdgeHTML versions of Edge.

```
function takepicture() {

    var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
    var b = document.getElementById('txtBrightness').value;
    if (width && height) {
        canvas.width = width;
        canvas.height = height;
        context.filter = 'brightness(' + b + '%)';
        context.drawImage(video, 0, 0, width, height);

        var data = canvas.toDataURL();

        //alert(data);
        document.getElementById('Image').value = data;
        //$("#Image").val(data);

        $("#form1").submit();
    } else {
        clearimage();
    }
}
```

From [this link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/filter), I know the the filter method not support the EdgeHtml version of Edge. Is there a workaround to make context filters work with the EdgeHTML versions of the Edge browser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try to use the Konva plugin to apply filter to an image.

Sample code as below (Change the image path to you owns, and I'm using Microsoft Edge 44.18362.449.0):

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/konva@4.1.3/konva.min.js"></script>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Konva Brighten Image Demo</title>
    <style>
        body {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            overflow: hidden;
            background-color: #f0f0f0;
        }

        #slider {
            position: absolute;
            top: 20px;
            left: 20px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container"></div><br />
    <input id="slider" type="range" min="-1" max="1" step="0.05" value="0" /><br />
    <script>
        function loadImages(sources, callback) {
            var images = {};
            var loadedImages = 0;
            var numImages = 0;
            for (var src in sources) {
                numImages++;
            }
            for (var src in sources) {
                images[src] = new Image();
                images[src].onload = function () {
                    if (++loadedImages >= numImages) {
                        callback(images);
                    }
                };
                images[src].src = sources[src];
            }
        }
        function buildStage(images) {
            var stage = new Konva.Stage({
                container: 'container',
                width: window.innerWidth,
                height: window.innerHeight
            });

            var layer = new Konva.Layer();

            var lion = new Konva.Image({
                image: images.lion,
                x: 80,
                y: 30,
                draggable: true
            });

            lion.cache();
            lion.filters([Konva.Filters.Brighten]);
            layer.add(lion);
            stage.add(layer);
            var slider = document.getElementById('slider');
            slider.oninput = function () {
                lion.brightness(slider.value);
                layer.batchDraw();
            };
        }

        var sources = {
            lion: '/images/Image1.jpg'
        };

        loadImages(sources, buildStage);
    </script>
```

The output like this:

[image]